# wxpython TextCtrl segmentation fault on SetValue

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm building a small app with wxglade.

It is basically just a TextCtrl multiline and readonly.
I start a thread that reads a file and display the content into the TextCtrl.
After a bunch of execution I get a segmentation Fault.

Debian 9
Python 3.5.3
wxpython 4.0.7.post2

Any suggestion?
Thanks a lot!

**Code**

```
import wx, threading, pdb
import gettext

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((400, 300))
        self.text_ctrl_1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
        self.update_text()

    def update_text(self):
        print("update_text")
        text = ""
        try:
            f = open("test.txt", "r")
            text = f.read()
            f.close()
        except:
            print(_('Error opening test.txt file!'))
            text = _('Error opening test.txt file!')

        self.text_ctrl_1.SetValue(text)
        threading.Timer(1, self.update_text).start()

    def __set_properties(self):
        self.SetTitle(_("frame"))

    def __do_layout(self):
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_1.Add(self.text_ctrl_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gettext.install("app") # replace with the appropriate catalog name

    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

**Error**

> update_text
>   update_text
>   update_text
>   update_text
>
> (wxglade_out.py:5127): Gtk-WARNING **: Invalid text buffer iterator:
>   either the iterator is uninitialized, or the
>   characters/pixbufs/widgets in the buffer have been modified since the
>   iterator was created. You must use marks, character numbers, or line
>   numbers to preserve a position across buffer modifications. You can
>   apply tags and insert marks without invalidating your iterators, but
>   any mutation that affects 'indexable' buffer contents (contents that
>   can be referred to by character offset) will invalidate all
>   outstanding iterators
>
> (wxglade_out.py:5127): Gtk-WARNING **: Invalid text buffer iterator:
>   either the iterator is uninitialized, or the
>   characters/pixbufs/widgets in the buffer have been modified since the
>   iterator was created. You must use marks, character numbers, or line
>   numbers to preserve a position across buffer modifications. You can
>   apply tags and insert marks without invalidating your iterators, but
>   any mutation that affects 'indexable' buffer contents (contents that
>   can be referred to by character offset) will invalidate all
>   outstanding iterators Segmentation fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that updating from within a thread will work properly.
Updates should be performed with the main GUI loop.
I don't know if this is related or not with gtk: [Gtk +3 TextView application crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780799/gtk-3-textview-application-crashes)

You can try updates via pubsub, some device of your own using variables or use a `wx.Timer` instead of a thread i.e.

```
import wx
import time

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((400, 300))
        self.text_ctrl_1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
        #self.update_text(None)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.update_text, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(5000)

    def update_text(self, event):
        print("update_text")
        self.text_ctrl_1.Clear()
        wx.GetApp().Yield() # to see the clear occur release momentarily to the main loop
        try:
            with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
               text = f.read()
        except:
            print(_('Error opening test.txt file!'))
            text = _('Error opening test.txt file!')
        time.sleep(2)
        self.text_ctrl_1.SetValue(text)

    def __set_properties(self):
        self.SetTitle("My frame")

    def __do_layout(self):
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_1.Add(self.text_ctrl_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you hit the problem!